# UI Testing with Xcode: How to find a button that has no title?

Tags: macos, xcode-ui-testing

I have some buttons in my user interface that only display an image and no title. How can I access them during a UI Test?  `window.buttons["delete"].click()` doesn't find the button due to lack of title. And I cannot set the title because the image has some transparency.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should set an `accessibilityIdentifier`. This is a non-user-facing property which was designed to allow you to identify elements in your UI tests. It was introduced to stop people from abusing `accessibilityLabel`, which people would previously use for identifying things in their tests, but which had an effect on the experience of Voiceover users, who hear the contents of `accessibilityLabel` when they select an element.

```
// app code
let myButton: UIButton!
myButton.accessibilityIdentifier = "deleteButton"

// test code
let app = XCUIApplication()
let deleteButton = app.buttons["deleteButton"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find buttons through the accessibilityLabel. So, first set the label:

```
deleteButton.setAccessibilityLabel("delete")
```

And then you can access it as normal with:

```
 untitledWindow.buttons["delete"].click()
```

Comment: This does work; however, be aware that the accessibility label is user-facing. The accessibility identifier is preferable, since it does not affect the user. Set the identifier in code, as shown in [@Oletha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44367605/1107226), or via Interface Builder. If one does want (or need) to use the label instead for some reason, though, make sure to name it something that would make sense to a person using voiceover.